# What happened to XBMC for Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-10.04, kodi, aptitude

I'm setting up an HTPC so I'm trying to install XBMC. Following the XBMC Team's [instructions](http://wiki.xbmc.org/?title=HOW-TO_install_XBMC_for_Linux_on_Ubuntu_with_a_minimal_installation_step-by-step#Installing_XBMC_Ubuntu_9.10_Karmic_or_higher), the commands run as expected until the second line, where apt-get reports that the package 'xbmc' wasn't found. I did an apt-cache search and the only result xbmc-related was

```
xbmc-ppa-keyring - GnuPG archive keys for the XBMC PPA
```

When I looked into the [Launchpad PPA site](https://launchpad.net/~team-xbmc), that was, indeed, the only package there. I'm using Ubuntu Lucid.
What's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out, the XBMC Team is [cleaning out the PPA](http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?p=582147#post582147) at the moment.
It might take a while until the packages are up.

Answer (score 0):

That guide is for Karmic, and you're running Lucid.  Chances are that package was never resubmitted or migrated to the Lucid servers.

Comment: That could be the case, but I looked into all of the folder systems, and that same package is the same for all distros.